# Java: Adding Change to be Calculated too

Tags: java

I am looking if anyone can help me figure out how to add to my code for it to also display the number of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies given the the number amount I input.

It is considered extra credit for my assignment, and I am curious to know how, but haven't found what I was looking for from similar questions like the one I am asking. Therefore, I'd appreciate if someone could help me out. (The dollar bill conversions work perfectly)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double userInput = 0.0;
    int bills;

    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of money you would like: ");
    userInput = inputScanner.nextDouble();

    if (userInput < 0.0) {
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
        inputScanner.close();
    }

    if (userInput > 0.0) {

        bills=(int)(userInput/20);
        System.out.println("You will receive:\n" + bills + " twenty dollar bills,");
        userInput=(userInput-(bills*20));
        bills=(int)(userInput/10);
        System.out.println(bills+" ten dollar bills,");
        userInput=(int)(userInput-(bills*10));
        bills=(int)(userInput/5);
        System.out.println(bills+" five dollar bills,");
        userInput=(userInput-(bills*5));
        bills=(int)(userInput/1);
        System.out.println(bills+" one dollar bills.");

    }

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're already printing out paper denominations; what is stopping you from doing the math to figure out the coinage too?

Comment: @Zephyr Truthfully, that is where I am running into an issue. Could you help me out? If not, no worries.

Comment: Just a sidenote: With `userInput < 0.0` and `userInput > 0.0`, you are missing on `userInput = 0.0`. What should happen in that case?

Comment: @Glains I have userInput = 0.0 defined as the defined value before the user assigns it.

Comment: you do realise that `bills=(int)(userInput/1)` actually means a simple assignment?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Hi Sharon, no, I did not realize that. If you are not going to help, but rather voice your opinion of my naiveness and lack of understanding, please don't. I am just looking for help.

Comment: With `(int) (userInput/20)`, you get the number of twenty dollar in your amount, with `(int) (userInput/k)`, you'd get the number of k dollar amount (and k can be any _double_). What is a quarter? ;)

Comment: What is the relationship between a dollar and a penny? Once you are done working with dollars you can start working with cents in the same way.

Comment: @ebigeon I understand the amounts and relationships. The problem I am having is when I create the new formulas to display the amount of q,d,k,p for the amount inputted it does not display anything in the console--only the bill amounts.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Is my problem I am having ^

Comment: I see no such code so I can't know what is wrong but did you think about my question?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Meaning 1 dollar = 100 pennies and such? I'll upload what I am trying to work out for the cents to display.

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with fractions of doubles can be tricky because of the aproximation that is done by the JVM. For example, the following code

```
double userInput = 123.39D;
double change = userInput - (int)userInput;  // suppose to be 0.39
System.out.println(change);
```

produces the output `0.39000000000000057`

A workaround for this would be to multiply by 100 and assign to an int. this effectively "moves" the first two decimal digits to the left of the dot, where it is easy to do the math to get the required nominations:

```
public static final int QUARTER = 25;
public static final int DIME = 10;
public static final int NICKEL = 5;

    double userInput = 123.39D;
    double changeDouble = userInput - (int)userInput;  // get smaller-than-1-dollar change
    int changeInt = (int)(changeDouble * 100);  // move two digits from right to left of decimal dot
    System.out.println("quarters: " + changeInt / QUARTER);
    changeInt -= (changeInt / QUARTER) * QUARTER;
    System.out.println("dimes: " + changeInt / DIME);
    changeInt -= (changeInt / DIME) * DIME;
    System.out.println("nickels: " + changeInt / NICKEL);
    changeInt -= (changeInt / NICKEL) * NICKEL;
    System.out.println("pennies: " + changeInt);
```

Comment: I think floating point aproximation is actually done by the hardware ...

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks.